# problems converting timestamp to new Date

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I have a timestamp of:

```
1399043514913
```

Which in reality is `Fri, 02 May 2014 15:11:54 GMT` but I'm getting `Sat, 05 Dec 46303 06:35:13 GMT`

How can i correctly convert the timestamp to the `Fri, 02 May` date?

I'm trying:

```
var dateTime = new Date(milliseconds * 1000);
var UTCString = new Date(dateTime).toUTCString();
```

What i really want to end up with is a Date object that i can use `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, etc on so i can put the date in any format i like.

Alternatively I'd like a way of converting `1399043514913` to `02/05/2014 15:11:54`

**Update:**

Problem solved thanks to @JensB,

Here's my millseconds to date format converter as a result:

```
function formatTimeStamp(milliseconds) {

    if (typeof milliseconds === "string")
        milliseconds = parseInt(milliseconds.match(/\d+/g)[0]);

    var dateTime = new Date(milliseconds);
    var dateVar = new Date(dateTime);
    var ISOString = new Date(dateVar).toISOString();
    var UTCString = new Date(dateVar).toUTCString();

    function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s.toString(); }

    var dateTimeParts = {
        dd: pad(dateVar.getDate()),
        MM: pad(dateVar.getMonth() + 1),
        yyyy: dateVar.getFullYear().toString(),
        yy: dateVar.getFullYear().toString().substring(2, 4),
        HH: pad(dateVar.getHours()),
        mm: pad(dateVar.getMinutes()),
        ss: pad(dateVar.getSeconds())
    };

    var execute = function(string) {

        for (var key in dateTimeParts)
            string = string.replace(key, dateTimeParts[key]);

        return string;
    };

    return {
        ISOString: ISOString,
        UTCString: UTCString,
        date: execute("dd/MM/yyyy"),
        time: execute("HH:mm"),
        dateTime: execute("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"),
        dateTimeParts: dateTimeParts 
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just running this code (same as in your question)

```
var dateTime = new Date(1399043514913);
var UTCString = new Date(dateTime).toUTCString();
alert(UTCString);
```

Gives me

> Fri, 02 May 2014 15:11:54 GMT

http://jsfiddle.net/DqSGJ/

Edit as per comment, this work?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dateTime = new Date(1399043514913);
    var dateVar = new Date(dateTime);
    var UTCString = dateVar.toUTCString();
    $("#dt").text(UTCString);
    $("#dt2").text("Month: "  + dateVar.getMonth());
    $("#dt3").text("GetDate: "  + dateVar.getDate());
});
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/DqSGJ/3/

Comment: Ok, you're right, that does return the correct UTC date now, i read that i had to do timestamp *1000 to get a valid date, my real battle is getting a usable date i can use getDate() on